# adding a constant to a foreach counter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Is there any way to define a new value that is a counter + a constant?

e.g.

```
\foreach\k in {0,1,...,7}
{
   \def\m    % ???? I want to make m=k+4
   \draw[->] (box\k) -- (box\m);
}
```

Comment: Please go also back to your list of questions: Many of them have answers, but you didn't accept them.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. It's frustrating, however, when the stackexchange software doesn't let you accept immediately; you have to come back later and that puts a barrier to being able to use the site efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I can't use the coordinates `box1` etc. here, I just print the values.

It is a common usage of `\foreach` for variables like `\m`, `\k` but I don't recommend that.

The calculation inside the loop and definition of `\youshoulduseothermacronames` is done with `\numexpr\k+4` here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach\k in {0,1,...,7}
{
  \def\youshoulduseothermacronames{\the\numexpr\k+4}    % ???? I want to make m=k+4
  \youshoulduseothermacronames\par

%   \draw[->] (box\k) -- (box\youshoulduseothermacronames);
}
\end{document}
```